# override Magento_Catalog in 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, overrides, custom-theme

I want to override prices in catalog module.

What I did was to test on actual phtml

```
 vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

It works as intended.

Now, to do it properly, I left file as it was originally and copied files and directory into my theme, made same modifications. Path where I copied files:

```
app/design/frontend/mysite/test/Magento_Catalog/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

But changes are not being applied. is that the path I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Folder path:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

There should be no `base` folder in it.

Don't forget to `static:content:deploy` and `flush:cache`.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately changes are still not working.

Comment: What is your vendor and theme name? can you please file path with code change?

Comment: vendor + path are: Es710/tk223/  code change are a couple of extra <br/> between span

Comment: vendor path and theme name.???

Comment: app/design/frontend/Es710/tk223/Magento_Catalog/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: `templates`folder is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a theme installed and setup in the backend: from Content/Configuration, you should be able to see if the theme is aplied correctly

Only need to do static:content:deploy if you are in production mode.

I have tried out on a demo site locally installed:

- prices have several templates and they are used all in different use cases:

--> the one that worked for me tonight is base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

--> I suggest you may copy the files under the folder base/templates/product/price and after test with your data in your catalog, you will see which templates are needed in your theme

--> I attach a screenshot of my theme folder for you to compare

[image]

Comment: Thansk Herve, theme is applied correctly.  Still, haven't found solution for it